# How do I get the correct case of a path?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small but itching problem. How do I get the correct case for a Windows path in Qt?

Let's say i have a path `c:\documents and settings\wolfgang\documents` stored in a `QString str` and i want to know the correct case, here `C:\Document and Settings\Wolfgang\Documents`. `QDir(str).absolutePath()` doesn't get me the path with correct case.

Any suggestions, since I have no clue what else i could try?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do this, but you can try doing a `QDir::entryList`, and then do a case insensitive search on the results. This will provide you with the correct filename. You'll then need to do that for all folder levels up to the root.

This should give you the preserved-case for the path/filename.

See [emkey08's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954785/1070129) for an example implementation.

Comment: Updated, a bit convoluted, but there's no nice simple way to do this unfortunately. -- I can't help wondering why you need a case-preserved path/filename on a case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: It's just for presenting the path to the user. They are used to correct cases of their paths.

Comment: How did the path end up all lower-case in the first place? I would rather fix that.

Comment: user entry I'm guessing from what Wolfgang has said.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution currently accepted by the OP, with listing all children items on each directory level of the path, is really inefficient, quick and dirty. There must be a better way. If you are developing for Windows, you can call to Windows API and write something like this:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
#include <Windows.h>

// Returns case-correct absolute path. The path must exist. 
// If it does not exist, returns empty string.
QString getCaseCorrectPath(QString path)
{
    if (path.isEmpty())
        return QString();

    // clean-up the path
    path = QFileInfo(path).canonicalFilePath();
        
    // get individual parts of the path
    QStringList parts = path.split('/');
    if (parts.isEmpty())
        return QString();

    // we start with the drive path
    QString correctPath = parts.takeFirst().toUpper() + '\\';

    // now we incrementally add parts one by one
    for (const QString &part : qAsConst(parts))
    {
        QString tempPath = correctPath + '\\' + part;

        WIN32_FIND_DATA data = {};
        HANDLE sh = FindFirstFile(LPCWSTR(tempPath.utf16()), &data);
        if (sh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return QString();
        FindClose(sh);

        // add the correct name
        correctPath += QString::fromWCharArray(data.cFileName);
    }
    
    return correctPath;
}
#endif
```

I have not tested it, there might be some minor issues. Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: This code won't work on macOS, where the used APFS file system is also **not** case sensitive by default.

Comment: You are right, my mistake... I updated the text a bit to not pretend it could work on macOS. It cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Following [ocodo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644880/1070129), here is a tested and working cross-platform implementation. You can use it with both **absolute** and **relative** paths. The path does **not** even have to **fully exist** (but obviously only existing path segments can be case-corrected).

Note that the returned path uses `/` separators, as this is the default cross-platform separator in Qt. So, you might want to use `QDir::toNativeSeparators` on Windows to get `\` separators.

```
QString caseFixedPath(const QString &path) {
    QString cleanedPath = QDir::cleanPath(path);
    QStringList caseFixedPath;
    
    // Keep moving to the next parent level of the path until it no longer contains any named segments.
    while (!QFileInfo(cleanedPath).isRoot() && !QString(cleanedPath).remove('/').remove('.').isEmpty()) {
        QString itemName = QFileInfo(cleanedPath).fileName();
        QString parentPath = QDir::cleanPath(cleanedPath + "/..");
        
        // Try to obtain the correctly cased item from the entry list of the parent directory.
        QString caseFixedItemName = QDir(parentPath).entryList({ itemName }).value(0);
        caseFixedItemName = caseFixedItemName.isEmpty() ? itemName : caseFixedItemName;
        
        // Combine the case fixed items into a case fixed path.
        caseFixedPath.prepend(caseFixedItemName);
        cleanedPath = parentPath;
    }
    
    caseFixedPath.prepend(cleanedPath);
    return QDir::cleanPath(caseFixedPath.join("/"));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfileinfo.html) for that and the function

`QString QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath () const` will return the absolute file path.

**E.g:**

```
QFileInfo yourFileInfo(yourPath);
QString correctedCasePath = yourFileInfo.absoluteFilePath ();
```

Another advantage is that, `yourPath` can be a `QFile` or `QString` so that you can use it directly with the *handle* currently you are having. Besides these, there are other operations are also available through `QFileInfo` that can obtain useful information about the file being referred to..

Hope it helps..

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work on Windows. QFileInfo("c:/windows").absoluteFilePath() gives 'C:/windows' instead of 'C:/WINDOWS'.