# how to find out if two filenames refer to the same file

Tags: c++, qt

This is a question about how to use Qt.
I  have two paths, let us say "c:\users\herbie\stuff\file1.txt" and "c:\users\HERBIE\stuff\file1.txt".

I want to write a method will tell me if these two paths refer to the same file or not. This method should work under windows and linux. Therefore I thought that Qt classes can be used to solve this problem, but I have not found how to do it.

Windows is not case sensitive so on windows these two refer to the same file. On linux they would refer to different files.

Does anybody know how to do this? string comparison does not work ( because of the case-sensitivity) and Qt classes such as QFileInfo,QDir etc always return the path the way it was set to them by constructor, not the name that actually exists on the system.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why won't string comparison work ? `std::string("HELLO") != std::string("hello")`

Comment: Because in a filesystem where case is ignored, `"HELLO.TXT"` is the same file as `"hello.txt"`.

Comment: that would work fine on  linux, because there the directory "HELLO" is not the same one as "hello", but on windows it is the same directory!

Comment: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfileinfo.html you might want to have a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write OS specific code using `#ifdef`s. If you are running on Windows, convert the paths into uppercase, and compare. If you are on Linux, then compare as it is. There are some predefined macros on each OS that you could use.

You could use the list from here: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

With this, your code would look something like:

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS__
// do case-insensitive compare
#else
// do case-sensitive compare
```

Comment: But even then, `/abc/../foo` and `/foo` are the same file. So is `/./././foo`. And what about hard-links, rebind mounts and the like? To be fair, the OP didn't specify if they wanted to check the same actual file or the same path.

Comment: If we are talking canonical filepaths, this will work. However, it won't work for a path that contains `..` and `.` unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, yeah, but the OP's question puts considerable emphasis on the case sensitivity issue, so I guessed he has already figured out how to get the absolute paths in those cases.

Comment: That's pretty much what Qt already does, so you don't need to.

Comment: To REALLY know if two paths, with different case-sensitivity and symlinks that maybe use [UNC-style paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows, etc, point to the very same file, the correct way is to really resolve what they point to and check if it's the same file/object. In this case you should use underlying platforms' functions or filesystem libraries, e.g as suggested by @odedsh. While Qt is very useful in resolving absolute/canonical paths, I'm not sure if it provides a way of checking equivalence in this extreme level.

Comment: Also note that path case-sensitivity is not a feature of the operating system, but a feature of volume's FileSystem. E.g FAT32 is not case-sensitive but Linux ext filesystems are. But then again, NTFS **is case-sensitive** by design but Windows doesn't allow you to create file names that differ only in for legacy software compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

`QFileInfo::operator==` is defined to return `true` if two paths refer to the same file, except when (A) one is a Windows 8.3 "short" name and the other is its "long" name or (B) when one is a symbolic link to the other. Neither exception applies here.

Comment: I looked through the Qt source code and the `QFileInfo::operator==` essentially just compares `canonicalFilePath`s of both `QFileInfo`s, either in CaseSensitive or CaseInsensitive mode depending on OS. This is both better and worse than using `boost`, which actually dives into the depths of the FS and compares the iNode numbers.


Also I do not understand why there is this remark about symlinks, since `canonicalFilePath` claims to remove all symlinks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Even better look at [`boost::filesystem::equivalent`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#equivalent) :)

It returns true, if `sf1 == sf2` and p1 and p2 resolve to the same file system entity, else false.

Comment: @ededsh, you should reference [`boost::filesystem::equivalent`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#equivalent) instead.

Comment: thanks! I will look at it, although I will probably not include Boost just to solve this annoying but minor  problem

Comment: @user3010236 Understood.  I will simply say that, despite the Boost Library's good&bad reputation, this library is one where the Boost portability definitely is worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I get the correct case of a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644863/how-do-i-get-the-correct-case-of-a-path) asks a similar question.

The solution by Slomojo is a bit of a hack, but there seems to be no way around it.

> There isn't a simple way to do this, but you can try doing a
>   `QDir.entryList`, and then do a case insensitive search on the results.
>   This will provide you with the correct filename. You'll then need to
>   get the `absolutePath` for that result.
>
> This should give you the preserved-case for the path/filename.

Comment: Thanks! but I think I will go with the suggestion of Happy to use #ifdef __WINDOWS__  . I had hoped to avoid that, but it still seems a lot faster than the solution suggested by Slomojo.